# Finding closest object to a source . (explanation question)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have this code which I basically got help from this forum from a really old post but I have a question in regard to how exactly does it work. There is a part in the code which we declare a float as `Mathf.Infinity` and we check to see if the distance between our source and all the objects (for loop) is less than that float then we return that object, but how does that really specify that it's the closest target? `(dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr)`?

```
 public GameObject GetClosestEnemy(List<GameObject> enemies, Transform fromThis)
{
    if (enemiesList == null) return null;
        GameObject bestTarget = null;
    float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 currentPosition = fromThis.position;
    foreach (GameObject potentialTarget in enemies)
    {
        Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.transform.position - currentPosition;
        float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
        if (dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr )
        {
            closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
            bestTarget = potentialTarget;
        }
    }
    return bestTarget;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Mathf.Infinity` is simply to initialize the variable to some invalid starting value that will be greater than any distance you measure between actual objects. If it was a reference type, this would be the equivalent of a `null` in this context.

```
        Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.transform.position - currentPosition;
        float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
```

This part here measure the distance between two objects in 3D space using basic vector math.

```
        if (dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr )
        {
            closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
            bestTarget = potentialTarget;
        }
```

Compares that computed distance to the current "closest" object. Since the initial value is "invalid", the first object will always be deemed as a "potentially closest" and stored. Subsequent objects in the loop will continue to check compare. If they are closer, then they are stored in the `bestTarget` value. If not, then the loop continues until no more objects are left to check.

After the loop ends, the value of `bestTarget` is returned, as it held the minimum distance of anything found within the loop.